# Bootstrap two tables side by side header issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I ran into an issue while trying to place two tables in the same bootstrap row. They appear just fine, however the panel-heading element gets cutoff because of some strange CSS restriction.

I noticed the issue starts when I try to add this line in:

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
```

Unfortunately this is somewhat required, as it will specify the table takes up 50% of width of the parent element. Does anyone have any advice on how to isolate the responsible CSS rule/how to fix this issue?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9d5k7Lv/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's required is to introduce another div around those with the class of panel.

Here's what it should look like:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
```

Here's an updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9d5k7Lv/12/